# How to incorporate prior knowledge after ML training?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability

Assuming I have trained my ML classifier on a balanced dataset with 5 classes. The model performs well with training and test data. The model's predicted confidence lines up well with the probability, so the predictions can immediately be used as $p(\mathcal C_k|\mathbf x_i)$, meaning the probability of class $\mathcal C_k$ given the input $\mathbf x_i$.

I use this model in production. Now I get a new bunch of data of which I certainly know it contains only classes 1, 2, and 3, and I know their approximate ratio. My model however sometimes mislabels these as classes 4-5. What would be the best approach to update the predictions? Some ideas:

- Set the predicted probabilites for classes 4-5 to $0$. However this would not consider if the new data contains significantly less of class 1, making it less likely.
- Multiply the predicted probabilites with the class distribution. This would set the probabilites for classes 4-5 to $0$, however it might lead to class 1 to not be predicted at all if there are only few samples of class 1 present.
- Retrain the model on the original training data, but only with classes 1-3. Problematic for big models with many classes.

Comment: What would you know about the new label distribution? I wonder if this is a question of how to be robust to this kind of change instead of how to incorporate the new (probably unknown) distribution into your predictions.

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Imagine categorising types of metals for recycling. You train your model with 5 types of metals, but on this day you get a load of metal from a recycler that only does iron and steel, no aluminium or whatever. They know, from experience, their load is about 70% steel. What would you do to help your model, that still predicts 5% aluminium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use an **ensemble of multiple classifiers** that will improve performance when your ML classifier breaks down[1], or implement **boosting** for your ML classifier assuming that it's a "weak" classifier[2].

References:

1. L.I. Kuncheva.  Combining Pattern Classifiers: Methods and Algorithms.  New York (NY), John Wiley and Sons, 2005.
2. R. Polikar.  Ensemble Based Systems in Decision Making.  IEEE Circuits and Systems Magazine. 6(3):21-45, 2006.